# Can't exclude a specific message from a remote logging

Tags: freebsd, syslog-ng

I manage logs FreeBSD 13.2  via `syslog-ng`. The current `syslog-ng` config has some lines to send data to a remote server (Debian 10 - 192.168.0.2:3000).

```bash
destination lc_net { tcp("192.168.0.2" port(3000) log_fifo_size(1000)); };

filter f_ntpd { not match("ntpd." value(MESSAGE)); };

log { source(src);
         if {
                 filter(f_devd);
                 filter(f_ntpd);
         }
          else {
                 destination(lc_net);
         };
};
```

So I try to filter that kind of message:

```c
Nov 28 13:47:23 host-example-fbsd kernel: ntpd.
```

But after reboot I always see this logline on the remote server.

I'm positive I have the wrong config, or I have a typo...

I bought the `syslog-ng` manual from here: [syslog-ng OSE 3.16 - Filters](https://www.syslog-ng.com/technical-documents/doc/syslog-ng-open-source-edition/3.16/administration-guide/51#TOPIC-956580).

My filters section:

```
#
# program filters
#
filter f_ppp { program("ppp"); };
filter f_slip { program("startslip"); };
filter f_devd { program("devd"); };
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the f_devd filter also match the message? Both filters should match, otherwise the else branch is used.

Comment: The `f_devd` filter doesn't work too.

Comment: I've added my filters section to the question.

Comment: Try something like this in your if branch: filter { filter(f_devd) or filter(f_ntpd) };
Simply listing the two filter expressions implies that both should match.